# CUDA dll loaded in R not returning correct values

Tags: c++, r, cuda

Following the instructions at [https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/#:~:text=Accelerate%20R%20using%20CUDA%20C/C%2B%2B/Fortran](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/#:%7E:text=Accelerate%20R%20using%20CUDA%20C/C%2B%2B/Fortran) I have written the following code in Visual Studio 2022:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void vectorAdd(const double* A, const double* B, double* C, int numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < numElements)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void VecAddGPU(double* A, double* B, double* C, int* n)
{
    // Device Memory
    double* d_A, * d_B, * d_C;

    // Define the execution configuration
    dim3 blockSize(256, 1, 1);
    dim3 gridSize(1, 1, 1);
    gridSize.x = (*n + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x;

    // Allocate output array
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, *n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B, *n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, *n * sizeof(double));

    // copy data to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, *n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, *n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // GPU vector add
    vectorAdd<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, *n);

    // Copy output
    cudaMemcpy(C, d_C, *n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);
}
```

Which I then build into a dll giving the following output:

```
Build started at 15:04...
1>------ Build started: Project: CUDA_VecAdd, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Compiling CUDA source file VecAdd.cu...
1>
1>C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\CUDA_VecAdd>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0   --machine 64 --compile -cudart shared  -g  -D_DEBUG -DCUDAVECADD_EXPORTS -D_WINDOWS -D_USRDLL -D_WINDLL -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb" -o C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\CUDA_VecAdd\x64\Debug\VecAdd.cu.obj "C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\CUDA_VecAdd\VecAdd.cu"
1>VecAdd.cu
1>tmpxft_000043a4_00000000-7_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp
1>LINK : C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\x64\Debug\CUDA_VecAdd.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>   Creating library C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\x64\Debug\CUDA_VecAdd.lib and object C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\x64\Debug\CUDA_VecAdd.exp
1>CUDA_VecAdd.vcxproj -> C:\Users\killi\source\repos\CUDA_VecAdd\x64\Debug\CUDA_VecAdd.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 15:04 and took 04.369 seconds ==========
```

I've included this dll file in a small R package for testing (in an ./inst/lib directory within the package) and written the following R wrapper:

```
#' VecAddGPU
#'
#' Elementwise addition of two vectors using the GPU.
#'
#' @param A First vector
#' @param B Second vector
#'
#' @return The resulting vector
#' @export
#'
VecAddGPU <- function(A, B)
{

  if(!is.loaded("VecAddGPU"))
  {
    dyn.load(system.file("lib/CUDA_VecAdd.dll", package = "CUDATEST"))
  }

  stopifnot(length(A) == length(B),
            is.numeric(A),
            is.numeric(B))

  n <- length(A)

  rst <- .C("VecAddGPU",
            A = as.double(A),
            B = as.double(B),
            C = double(length = n),
            n = as.integer(n),
            PACKAGE = "CUDA_VecAdd")

  return(as.numeric(rst$C))
}
```

After some testing in the console I get the following output:

```
> library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
> document()
ℹ Updating CUDATEST documentation
ℹ Loading CUDATEST
> install()
── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\killi\Desktop\CUDATEST/DESCRIPTION' (355ms)
─  preparing 'CUDATEST':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building 'CUDATEST_0.1.0.tar.gz'
   
Running "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL "C:\Users\killi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYhKZ9S/CUDATEST_0.1.0.tar.gz" --install-tests 
* installing to library 'C:/Users/killi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3'
* installing *source* package 'CUDATEST' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (CUDATEST)
> library(CUDATEST)
> A <- 1:4
> B <- 5:8
> A + B
[1]  6  8 10 12
> VecAddGPU(A, B)
[1] 0 0 0 0
>
```

The host CUDA code seems to be working fine as when I add the lines

```
// Debugging
double test = 1.5;
C[0] = test;
```

to the end of the CUDA code, rebuild the dll, rebuild the R package, etc., I get the following output:

```
> A <- 1:4
> B <- 5:8
> A + B
[1]  6  8 10 12
> VecAddGPU(A, B)
[1] 1.5 0.0 0.0 0.0
>
```

I've tried several things but I'm lost here. Why am I not getting the expected output from the `VecAddGPU(A, B)` call? What is going wrong?

I've tried making changes to the CUDA code following Nvidia's samples, but this hasn't changed anything about the behavior. I keep getting the `0 0 0 0` output where I would expect `6 8 10 12`.

Edit:

I'm new to CUDA so excuse me if this is not very elegant.

```
// System includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// CUDA runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// Helper functions and utilities to work with CUDA
#include <helper_functions.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>

__global__ void vectorAdd(const double* A, const double* B, double* C, int numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < numElements)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void VecAddGPU(double* A, double* B, double* C, int* n)
{
    cudaError_t code;
    cudaError_t err;

    // Device Memory
    double* d_A, * d_B, * d_C;

    // Define the execution configuration
    dim3 blockSize(256, 1, 1);
    dim3 gridSize(1, 1, 1);
    gridSize.x = (*n + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x;

    // Allocate output array
    code = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, *n * sizeof(double));
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    code = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B, *n * sizeof(double));
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    code = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, *n * sizeof(double));
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    // copy data to device
    code = cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, *n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    code = cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, *n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    // GPU vector add
    vectorAdd<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, *n);
    err = cudaGetLastError();
    /*if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(err);
    }*/

    // Copy output
    code = cudaMemcpy(C, d_C, *n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    // Debugging
    double test = 1.5;
    C[0] = test;

    // Free memory
    code = cudaFree(d_A);
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    code = cudaFree(d_B);
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }

    code = cudaFree(d_C);
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        exit(code);
    }
}
```

The code above runs, but returns the wrong answer. When I uncomment the check after the kernel call it crashes R, so I guess that's where things go wrong. Is there an easy way to pass error messages to R?

Comment: try using [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) in your CUDA code

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have added variables to store cudaErrors and have figured out that things go wrong at the GPU kernel call. Passing the cudaError as an integer back to R reveals that it's error 209: cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice (see https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038:~:text=cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice).

I'll move on from here and try to fix it, but any idea what might cause it?

Edit: I realize that the Quadro M1000M is SM 5.0, while the build output from VS shows sm_52 and compute_52...

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.  You need to compile your CUDA code for a device architecture that matches the device you are running on.  With no specification, currently, it defaults to cc5.2, which won't work on your cc5.0 GPU.

Comment: I suspect it's unlikely that your R application will be happy if/when your DLL calls `exit()`.  If you want to pass a numerical value (e.g. status) back to R, I imagine one way to do that would be to define an additional pointer parameter in your `VecAddGPU` function, and allocate storage for a buffer in R, pointed to by that argument, and pass your status back that way.  After updating status in the buffer, you can use `return;` in place of `exit(code);` in your error-handling sections.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing for the kernel call. Thanks!